# Top or parent in JavaScript is undefined in SharePoint 2010 using FireFox or Opera

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, iframe

I'm trying to access the URL of a SharePoint page from within an iframe. It workes fine in IE 9. But not in Firefox or Opera. If I move the script into a common ASP.NET application it works in all browsers.

What is happening in SharePoint when it comes to top and parent?

I have tried with `top.location.href`, but the problem persists.

This is my JavaScript code:

```
  try {
    var url = parent.location.href;
    alert(url);
    var index = url.indexOf('SitePages');
    if (index) {
      alert(index);
      url = url.substring(0, index);
      alert(url);
    }

    alert('done');
  }
  catch (ex) {
    alert(ex.Message);
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're not affected by cross-domain restrictions?

Comment: Will that work differenly in different browsers?

Comment: Change `ex.Message` to `ex`, then reload the page and open the console (FF: Ctrl + shift + J). What error messages do you see?

Comment: Thank you then I got a real error message. Error: Permission denied to access property 'href'. So you are right it is cross-domain restrictions. post in I give it a checked. Know of any setting in the browser to make it act like IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're experiencing the cross-domain (aka cross-origin) scripting restrictions. If you're the maintainer of the server, the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control#Overview) about the [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control#Access-Control-Allow-Origin) header may interest you. This response header should be sent along with your framed web page in order to unlock the ability to script across domains.